# JavaMail - IMAP: A1 NO LOGIN failed

Tags: java, email, office365, jakarta-mail, imap

I know this question has been asked before a couple times but I have tried every solution I found in each question and none of them worked. I have a java application that connects to a mail and downloads all the attachments from the emails, the applications has been working fine for over 1 month but suddenly today it stopped working with one specific email, with all the other emails I normally use the app it's working perfectly, even after trying all the possible solutions I found I'm getting the same `A1 NO LOGIN failed.`

It has always worked with the username and password I use, I made sure the password wasn't changed by logging in using outlook and outlook web, and both worked fine. I don't think is something with the firewall because its working fine with all the other emails I'm using, its just this one email that suddenly doesn't works.

The emails I'm using to connect are from my job which has a custom domain with office365, e.j.

> mail@mydomain.com

I tried the application in the morning and it worked fine with that specific email, a few hours later I'm getting the follow message from an exception:

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: LOGIN failed.
   at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:732)
   at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)
   at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
```

**and the debugger returns the following:**

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.6.2
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle]
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG IMAPS: enable STARTTLS
DEBUG IMAPS: closeFoldersOnStoreFailure
DEBUG IMAPS: trying to connect to host "outlook.office365.com", port 993, isSSL true
* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready. [QgBOADYAUABSADEAOQBDAEEAMAAwADYAMgAuAG4AYQBtAHAAcgBkADEAOQAuAHAAcgBvAGQALgBvAHUAdABsAG8AbwBrAC4AYwBvAG0A]
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: XOAUTH2
DEBUG IMAPS: protocolConnect login, host=outlook.office365.com, user=theEmail@MyDomain.biz, password=<non-null>
DEBUG IMAPS: mechanism PLAIN disabled by property: mail.imaps.auth.plain.disable
DEBUG IMAPS: mechanism LOGIN not supported by server
DEBUG IMAPS: mechanism NTLM not supported by server
DEBUG IMAPS: mechanism XOAUTH2 disabled by property: mail.imaps.auth.xoauth2.disable
DEBUG IMAPS: LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAPS: LOGIN command result: A1 NO LOGIN failed.
```

**my code is as follows:**

```
public MailData office() {
        MailData DATA= new MailData();
        String PROTOCOL = "imaps", HOST = "outlook.office365.com", ENCRYPTION_TYPE = "tls", PORT = "993";
        DATA=readEmail(PROTOCOL, HOST, uname, pwd, ENCRYPTION_TYPE, PORT);
        return DATA;
    }

public MailData readEmail(String PROTOCOL, String HOST, String USER, String PASSWORD, String ENCRYPTION_TYPE, String PORT) {
    MailData INFO=new MailData();
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", PROTOCOL);
    props.setProperty("mail.debug.auth ","true");
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.ssl.enable", "true");
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.port",PORT);
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.auth.plain.disable", "true");
    
    try{
        MailSSLSocketFactory sf = new MailSSLSocketFactory();
        sf.setTrustAllHosts(true);
        props.put("mail.imaps.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.imaps.ssl.socketFactory", sf);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
        session.setDebug(true);
        Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
        store.connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD);
        ////////////REST OF THE CODE
```

I know the code is not perfect, but it works with any other email I'm using it with, its just this one specific email that suddenly stopped working, please help, I don't know what else to do or try.

Comment: Your admin may have disabled plain text login.  This is getting more common in hosted Office 365 instances.  Have you asked them?

Comment: The server only supports PLAIN (and XOAUTH2) authentication and you've disabled it in your application.  If you're expecting the server to support NTLM authentication, the admin may have disabled that.  Also, you can [get rid of all the socket factory settings](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes), and if you really need to set "trust all hosts" (which you shouldn't), you can just set it using the property [`mail.imaps.ssl.trust`](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/package-summary.html#mail.imap.ssl.trust) set to "*".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving the plain password,create a app password and use it.It will work.

Steps
Login to Office 365 
Got MYAccount-->Security and Privacy-->Additional security verification-->Create and manage app passwords